# Setting X to use 800x480

Tags: pi-4, config.txt

For some reason, despite settings in /boot/config.txt when I start X windows it goes with a resolution of 1024x768.  I have a 5 inch screen with that uses 800x480.  How can I reconfigure X to use a resolution that is not 1024x768?

`tvservice -s state 0xa [HDMI CUSTOM RGB full 4:3], 1024x768 @ 60.00Hz, progressive`

````
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=2
#hdmi_mode=9
#hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 3 0 0 0
hdmi_safe=1```
````

Comment: Do you get the correct resolution before X is started?

Answer (score 0):

At the desktop, try Preferences -> Screen Configuration

Your hardware framebuffer resolution (set in config.txt) does not have to be the same resolution as the X11 desktop.  X11 has the ability to create larger virtual desktops that you pan around inside of with a lower resolution hardware view into it.

Comment: How would one change that without being in X11?  Any menu item to close to the bottom is off screen and panning does not work.  I can vnc in and change it but that's a whole separate X11 instance it seems and doesn't stick.

Comment: Did not realize panning was off.  Were you root when you tried it through VNC?  The /var/log/Xorg.0.log file will help you debug what is going on.  Hard to know how things got out of sync.  Also, xrandr might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51907